# Lock parts of document in CRM to word integration

Tags: ms-word, crm

We are looking into using CRM MS Word integration to produce customer documents.

We have a requirement that certain legal texts should always be included and not changed. The user should be able to change other parts of the document.

Is this possible? Or is it such that if you give the user access to Word he can change anything.

Comment: What happens to customers who do not have word? :)

Comment: @Moo, the customer always gets a printed copy, the user here is an internal user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at section protection in Word. You can protect sections in Word and restrict editing.